# Found a bullet shell with 'Winchester 30-06 SPRG' on it, how old is it?

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, identification

The shell is a dark brown.. I don't know much about guns but anyone know anything?

Comment: Please add a photo!

Comment: The [.30-06 Springfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.30-06_Springfield) was in service from 1906 – 1980s.

Comment: Without more information such as where the shell casing was found, and a picture, there isn't much we can do for this question.

Answer (score 1):

"Winchester 30-06 SPRG" is a marking I'd expect to find on a [.30-06 Springfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.30-06_Springfield) cartridge.

The .30-06 was adopted by the US Army in 1906, and has been a highly popular cartridge for both military and civilian uses ever since.  Your cartridge could be over a hundred years old, or it could have been manufactured yesterday.